# Swing JFrame like alert Display

Tags: swing

How to Apply JDialogPane Propery to JFrame. when i click out side of the JFrame It shouldnt minize. It should present like alert.  i Put JFrame into JDialog. But i didnt get expected output .

Comment: It's difficult to parse your question. I realize that English is not your first language, but you should take a little more time to get it right. If not for yourself, then out of respect for the people who take the time to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class extends JPanel. For a depth analysis read this [extends JDialog to create your own dialog](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/extendsJDialogtocreateyourowndialog.htm)
I hope this will be usefull to you!

Answer (score 0):

[Jide components](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/component.htm) has an excellent solution for alerts, see the [web start demo](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/download.htm) and filter for "alert"

It's commercial, but like all Jide components, they are well worth their money.